# Evaluating an integral involving hyperbolic functions and exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I'm interested in evaluating the following integral, which I encountered while working on a special partition function $\int_{0}^{+\infty} a^{2}\sinh(x)^{2} e^{-ba\cosh(x)}dx$. Even an aproximate solution is accepted.

Comment: Hve you tried integration by parts with $u=\sinh(x)$ and $dv=\sinh(x) e^{-ba\cosh(x)}dx$?

Comment: Something Bessel like probably

Comment: @TitoEliatron not yet, I'll try later

Comment: @YuriyS I haven't studied them yet, I'm still an high-schooler. Could you please show me what you mean?

Comment: I'm on my phone, can't type formulas, just look up Modified Bessel functions, integral definitions. Also I suggest using Wolfram Alpha, it could give you the exact expression

Comment: @YuriyS ok, I'll look at that. I've already tried with Wolfram Alfa but I didn't get any answer

Answer (score 5):

This is basically the same as

$$I(c)=\int_0^\infty \sinh^2(x) e^{-c \cosh(x)}dx$$

Use

$$\sinh^2(x) =\cosh^2(x)-1   $$

Modified Bessel function of the second kind:

$$K_0(c) =\int_0^\infty e^{-c \cosh(x)}dx $$

Using Feynman's trick of differentiation under the integral sign, we have:

$$I(c)=-K_0(c)+\frac{d^2}{d c^2} K_0(c)=K_1(c)/c$$

Here we used properties of Bessel functions from Wikipedia

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is there a series expansion for $K_{0} (c)$ and $K_{1}(c)?$

Comment: @GabrielePrivitera, there is, but whether or not it works depends on the parameters. Bessel functions can be evaluated by most of the modern programs like Matlab or Mathematica and they can be considered a sufficient answer on their own, without the need to specify how they should be calculated

Comment: Copy that, thank for your help!